# Stored Procedure Function Import vs Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, sql-server, model-view-controller, ef-code-first

I have taken over an existing project written beautifully in SQL with many useful and clean stored procedures.

I was told as a bonus that I should make several additions and ideally re-write the code in MVC.

I have so far have generated my datamodels and created function imports and complex types.

It has been fun, but now I am feeling bad that I never used a true Entity Framework Code First scenario.  I would of had a more succinct code, smoother validation and more MVC purist friends.

What do you think?
What would you have done?
I have a theory that there will be significant changes ahead anyhow to the Entity Framework Code First scenario, so pure SQL is a safer choice.

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code first makes more sense when prototyping or doing some kind of RAD development. Since you already had your SQL data model developed, there is no benefit to taking a code-first approach. You can develop clean code either way.

Comment: What about validation, Just use Custom Server and Client in JavaScript/JQuery?

Comment: Validation annotations are nice in Code First but yes there are many health alternatives.  ASP field validations and client/server side code.

Answer (score 1):

If the database code was a mess, buggy or complex then I could see replacing it with EF but if it works don't break it.